# Загрузка большого количества файлов

Tags: php, файлы, download, highload

Как реализовать загрузку большого количества файлов (10, 50, 100 тыс. файлов)? К примеру у меня есть большое количество, порядка 10 тыс., ссылок на различные изображение, каким образом все эти 10 тыс. можно быстро и эффективно скачать к себе на сервер? Сейчас мне удалось добиться только 3 тыс. файлов, дальше сервер останавливает работу скрипта. Будут полезны любые подсказки, в каком направлении вообще смотреть?

Comment: если к себе -- rsync

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov , если не сложно, можете привести пример использования rsync  для загрузки файла по url. Полистал гугл, там везде говориться только про работу с внутренними файлами на сервере, другими словами перемещение с места на место.

Comment: Зачем по урл; если это ваш сервер, грузите по ssh

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov , так вся фишка в том, что все файлы нужно скачивать из вне, по урлу.

Comment: это VPS? скрипт запускается через http запрос?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov , на данный момент это хостинг, но если нужно для решения этого вопроса VPS, можем переехать на VPS. Скрипт можно запускать по разному, как с http, так и через командную строку.

Comment: т. е. сервер останавливает работу скрипта, если его запустить через командную строку? если да, то интересно почему.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov , да, даже через запуск с командой строки работа скрипта останавливается. Может быть потому что это все же хостинг, а не VPS, но это одно из предположений.

Comment: Можно список загрузок на несколько частей разделить

Comment: А вы проверяли ответ скрипта, что он вам отвечает на момент прекращения? Или сервер в односторронем порядке убивает процесс? Что именно происходит на срвере и в скрипте?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , процесс просто убивается и прекращается работа

Comment: @Slam тогда имеет смысл переходить на свою VPS, либо писать техподдержке насчёт уточнения лимита времени для процессов.